# Spring Integration calling Apache Solr RESTful service

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration

I would like to call Apache Solr using Spring Integration. Solr provides RESTful like features for searching e.g. I want to call: `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ccy/query?q=id:*&wt=json`  this will return a **json** string.

So the plan is to provide a ReferenceData Controller which calls a service which in turn will call Solr via spring integration. But I need the response to be Synchronous.

I have looked at the sample Spring Integration code provided and came across rest-http example . But it want over my head. So how can I do this and any code sample would be useful.

Thanks
GM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest sample is concentrated on the server side; on the client side, you'd need something like...

```
<int:gateway id="toRest" default-request-channel="foo" service-interface="ToRest" />

<int:channel id="foo" />

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="out" request-channel="foo"
    http-method="GET"
    url="http://localhost:8983/solr/ccy/query?q=id:{currency}&amp;wt=json">
        <int-http:uri-variable name="currency" expression="headers['currency']"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

With `ToRest` being a Java interface with a method something like `String toRest(String in)`; inject the ToRest instance into your controller and just send an empty String "".

However, I think that `#` in the middle of the URL is going to give you trouble.

EDIT:

Added `uri-variable` - the expression can be any SpEL expression, e.g. `payload.currency` (calls `getCurrency()` on the message payload); `headers['currency']`; or `@someBean.determineCurrency(payload)`; etc, etc.

Your gateway can populate the header...

`String result(@Payload String payload, @Header("currency") String currency);`

Of course, since you are only doing a GET, you could simply set the currency in the payload and just use `expression="payload"`.

Comment: Gary, thanks that is exactly what I did. And yes removed the '#' it should have been ..../solr/ccy/.... I have one more question. I need the some parts of the URL to be dynamic e.g. ?q=id:*  can be changed to ?q=id:GBP so how can I change this on the fly in Spring Integration?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the hash tag, please have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the web server